# Read-only permissions for Bit-Bucket server

Tags: macos, bitbucket

when trying to push to BitBucket I get the following error message:

```
fatal: remote error: Insufficient permissions
You cannot push to XX/repository. Pushing requires write access and your
access is read-only.
```

Our BitBucket server does not run through ssh-keys but rather more with my account credentials and the osxkeychain. Clone and pull works perfectly and I have the error since I installed xcode, however, uninstalling xcode does not help.
I appreciate any idea!